# Cardbus sound card not auto-detected

Tags: 12.04, soundcard

I'm running 12.04 and I have a Creative X-fi "cardbus" sound card. It works fine if I boot the computer with the card already inserted; but if I insert it after boot, it is not detected. Also dmesg shows absolutely nothing after inserting the card.
It was working on Ubuntu 11.04. Is there anything I can do to make it auto-detect again?
Failing that, any command I could issue to manually make the computer detect it without having to reboot?

Thanks,
Cristian

Update: I tried to add "pcie_aspm=force" to the boot options (someone told me it might help) but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not putting that in while the computer is on as it could fry something. But nonetheless after you install it try running this command in terminal. (It resets your desktop environment and may kick your driver into starting.)

```
sudo --unity replace
```

Very Respectfully,

Matthew Kaulfers

Comment: Matthew, thank you for your reply.
I'm not an expert but I think one of the features of cardbus is to be hot-swappable and hot-pluggable?
Anyway, I tried unity --replace but it didn't help - and I suppose it's not a driver thing because if it was just a missing driver, lspci or dmesg should at least show the presence of the card... right?